# Should I tell a prospect manager that I am waiting on another offer?

Tags: recruitment, manager, hiring

I am in a situation where I have company A extending a job offer.

But I am waiting on company B who I'd like to work for more to extend a job offer which they have not yet.

I was wondering if it would be ok to tell my would be manager about the situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I inform my recruiter that I am likely in the final round of interview with another company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153286/should-i-inform-my-recruiter-that-i-am-likely-in-the-final-round-of-interview-wi)

Comment: @gnat that sounds slightly different.  In this post the OP has a firm offer.  In the post you cite it sounds like the poster thinks it's likely they will get an offer, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I would definitely tell B that you have an offer on the table — most hiring managers have a lackadaisical attitude and this will drive them to make an offer quicker, if they are considering it.

You could also notify A as well and drive counter offers but of less importance to the question.

Comment: good call. comp. B did not move through. Its good i checked in. whew.

Comment: although i checked with hr instead of the hiring manager which i couldve. you think it would have made a difference?

Answer (score 2):

It’s better to tell company B today “I have another offer” than telling them in two weeks time “thanks for your offer, but you were too slow”.