# After rejection letter company calls for second interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment

This is related to my old post
here:
[Should I tell a prospect manager that I am waiting on another offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183061/should-i-tell-a-prospect-manager-that-i-am-waiting-on-another-offer)

A month after I got a rejection letter the company called for second interview and this time with their HR supervisor.

What would I expect from this interview?

Comment: Well, the obvious thing to do is to ask them, they hopefully know more about what they're doing than some random folks on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an interview. Most likely they had someone who looked like a really good candidate, hired them, sent everyone else a rejection letter, and within a month that really good looking candidate turned out to be a nightmare - so they fired them and called everyone back for interviews even after a rejection, as long as they were any good at all.

So your position is: You were good enough in your first interview to be asked back. They will not have that many candidates (for example three of five candidates they called again may have already found a new job, so you are only competing with one candidate). They are under pressure to hire someone; you may have a lot of work cleaning up the mess someone else created in one month.

All in all, it's a good chance to get that job with a good contract.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer!. I also have a job but I was curious as i havent come a cross this situation before. ill update with the result after i finish the interview.

Comment: My guess is that the rejection said something like "...your skills/experience do not match up with our needs AT THIS TIME."  Their needs have changed and now you are back in the game as a candidate.  You don't need to know why, just that it's happened.

Answer (score 1):

Having watched both the company I worked for, and other companies I know about, struggle to fill positions; the most likely reason for the company restarting the search process is that they were ghosted. This trend has grown since the health crisis.

We have been ghosted on the first day of work. One never came back after lunch. We have been rejected the weekend before their first day of work. Some never responded to the formal offer letter. That doesn't even count the people who skipped scheduled interviews.

At home we have found that you might need to schedule 5-7 visits from contractors just to get 3 estimates for the new roof.  They reschedule, they skips appointments, they never send you an estimate.

We now think that you need to not just pick one person for the job opening, but you need to pick three and don't tell the 2nd and 3rd best that they didn't get the job until after the new person starts.

If the company is wanting you to restart the process, and you potentially want to work for them, then there is little risk in talking to them.

Before the health crisis the reason why there would be a pause and then restarting the hiring process was due to a funding issue, or some other issue that made the company want to hold off for a few months. It was also possible that they made a bad choice and want to bring in some good candidates who they already have resumes for to speed the next hiring action.